# NumberVerify: missing return statement

Tags: java

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class NumberVerify
{
    public static boolean isOdd( int num )
    {
      if((num%2)==0)
         {
            boolean yes = true;
            return true;
         }

    }
    public static boolean isEven( int num )
    {
      if((num%2)!=0)
         {
            boolean yes = false;
              return false;
         }

    }   
}
```

The error messages say "missing return statements" on the }'s.

I tried adding

```
return true;
```

after the set of braces nested by

```
if((num%2)==0)
```

and did something similar with the

```
if((num%2!=0)
```

nest, although with

```
return false;
```

That only caused the isOdd to pop up as true and isEven to pop up as false regardless of the inputted number itself.

Here is the runner program.

import static java.lang.System.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class NumberVerifyRunner
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        //add in input
        System.out.println("5 is odd :: " + NumberVerify.isOdd(5));
        System.out.println("5 is even :: " + NumberVerify.isEven(5));

      System.out.println("0 is odd :: " + NumberVerify.isOdd(0));
        System.out.println("0 is even :: " + NumberVerify.isEven(0));

      System.out.println("2 is odd :: " + NumberVerify.isOdd(2));
        System.out.println("2 is even :: " + NumberVerify.isEven(2));


        //add in more test cases
    }
}
```

How do I fix the missing return statements in the NumberVerify class?

Comment: You don't have a return on all possible conditions so your method may not return in some cases, which is invalid considering it has a return value.

Comment: In your methods, what if the IF condition is not true; what is your method is supposed to return? Compiler faced similar challenge, so it threw an error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a value if the 'if' clause is not satisfied.
All code blocks need to return a value. This solution should work well.

```
public static boolean isOdd(int num) {
    if ((num % 2) == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean isEven(int num) {
    if ((num % 2) != 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding return false after the first if statement and return  true after the second.

Also you could just return the result of num%2==0 without the if statement due to the fact that num%2==0 is a boolean value. So you could also delete the if statements and do return( num%2)==0;

For the other one do return (num%2 )!=0;

Comment: Let me know if this helps with a comment

Answer (score 0):

`isOdd` and `isEven` must return boolean for all branches.

> This will work 
>       import static java.lang.System.*;

```
public class NumberVerify
{
    public static boolean isOdd( int num )
    {
        return numr%2 == 1;
    }
    public static boolean isEven( int num )
    {
      return num % 2 == 0;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java your return statement is the last statement. In your case just change whit following code

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class NumberVerify
{
    public static boolean isOdd(int num)
    {
        if(num%2 == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    public static boolean isEven( int num )
    {
        if(num%2 !=0 )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   import static java.lang.System.*;

   public class NumberVerify 
   {
       public static boolean isOdd( int num ) 
       {
          if((num%2)!=0)
          {
            boolean yes = true;           
          }
          return yes;
       }

       public static boolean isEven( int num )
       {
          if((num%2)==0)
           {
            boolean yes = true;         
           }
          return yes;
        }   
    }
```

Your code have the return statement is out of the scope.
 Method signature have return the boolean value but you put return statement if() control scope only so you change the public scope(current method scope).

Answer (score 0):

> Your All code path will not return values:

Consider your code :

```
 public static boolean isOdd( int num )//Assume num as 7
    {
      if((num%2)==0)// 7 % 2 will be 1 , condition fails 
         {
            boolean yes = true;
            return true;// this statement won't be executed 
         }
      // you have no return statement here 

    }
```

import static java.lang.System.*;

```
public class NumberVerify
{
    public static boolean isOdd( int num )
    {
        boolean isOddNumber = (num %2 ) !=0 
        return isOddNumber;

    }
    public static boolean isEven( int num )
    {
       boolean isEvenNumber = (num %2 )==0 
       return isEvenNumber;
   }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you give a `return` to a `if` and forgot the `else`. In your method `isOdd()` the `return` is only in the `if` not in the method. you may change your code like this.

```
public static boolean isOdd( int num )
{
  if((num%2)==0)
     {
        boolean yes = true;
        return true;
     } else {// you must add the else
         return true;// return a boolean value here.true or false,it's up to you.
     } 
  // Or add a return below without add the else.
  return ture;// true or false,it's up to you.
}
public static boolean isEven( int num )
{
  if((num%2)!=0)
     {
        boolean yes = false;
          return false;
     } else {// you must add the else
         return true;// return a boolean value here.true or false,it's up to you.
     } 
  // Or add a return below without add the else.
  return ture;// true or false,it's up to you.
}
```

Comment: Remember that, your method go into a `if-else`,every possiable condition must return a result back to the method. Or the method has it's own return.